# Given a sequence an from 1 to infinity, is the sequence bounded above? (Does it have an upper bound). If not, why not?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Given a sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ with the conditions that there exists a positive number $U$ such that $a_n\le U$, $n\ge101$, is the sequence bounded above? If so, find an upper bound of the sequence. If not, why not.

[image]

Not sure how to approach this problem

Comment: Try to construct a specific sequence that satisfies this condition.  See if you can make a sequence unbounded above.

Comment: take the sequence ${n^2}$ which is bounded below but not above ($n^2>0,  ∀n∈ℕ$). How does this help me with this problem? Yes, I can find a specific sequence that satisfies the condition but how to apply it to this problem?

Comment: The sequence $n^2$ doesn't help because it doesn't satisfy the condition.  Now if you tried to make a sequence that does satisfy it, before you got the answer from someone, you might have actually discovered the solution yourself.

Comment: @user8960 thanks, should have realized that before. answer seems obvious now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not $a_n\le \max\{a_1,\cdots,a_{100}, U\}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}?$

Comment: so then it's bounded above?

Comment: Yes. Moreover we have an upper bound given explicitly.